# Span<T> and friends not working in .NET Native UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native, system.memory

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Visual Studio 2017 with latest update.
2. Create a UWP project targetin 10240 (this is not mandatory, it's broken in all builds)
3. Install `System.Memory` from nuget packages (click include prerelease)
4. Copy paste this code in to MainPage.cs

   ```
   private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      void Recursive(ReadOnlySpan<char> param)
      {
          if (param.Length == 0) return;

          tx1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

          tx1.Text += new string(param.ToArray());
          Recursive(param.Slice(1));
      }

      ReadOnlySpan<char> mySpan = "Why things are always broken in Visual Studio".AsSpan();

      Recursive(mySpan);
   }
   ```
5. Copy paste this to MainPage.xaml

   ```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <TextBlock x:Name="tx1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   FontSize="48" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   </Grid>
   ```
6. Switch from Debug to Release x64 and make sure "Compile with .Net Native tool chain".
7. Click Play.
8. Receive this error:

> ------ Build started: Project: App12, Configuration: Release x64 ------
>     App12  c:\Users\myuser\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App12\App12\bin\x64\Release\App12.exe
>     Processing application code
>   C:\Users\myuser.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Internal compiler error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

What I'm doing wrong? This works in Debug and release without .NET Native. Thanks.

Comment: "`Span<T>` and friends", how did you get to that conclusion? Does it compile if you remove those references? What about without recursion?

Comment: If I remove System.Memory and this Span<T> code the app compiles in .Net Native. If you follow the steps, It won't compile. If I remove the recursive it doesn't work either. It's the nuget package.

Comment: Does this happen also with e.g. `char[]` type?

Comment: If I remove the Span<T> code and add char[] is fine. So the problem is the System.Memory Span<T> and friends thingy.

Comment: "Internal compiler error" message suggests that you might have better luck posting this to .net native issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> System.Memory is in prerelease status and doesn't work yet with .NET Native. The next version of .NET Native compiler will have support for this.

https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/5725